# find keys from dynamiclly generated array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a code which generates an array object like this

```js
[{
    "invoiceNumber": "INV-056",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-06-19",
    "jobCardNumber": "JC-018",
    "tax": 43323,
  }, {
    "invoiceNumber": "INV-056",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-06-19",
    "jobCardNumber": "JC-018",
    "tax": 213,
    "part@18%": 140.04,
    "part@12%": 140.04,
    "part@9%": 140.04,
    "labour@18%": 140.04,
    "offer@12%": 140.04,
    "offer@9%": 140.04,
  }, {
    "invoiceNumber": "INV-056",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-06-19",
    "jobCardNumber": "JC-018",
    "tax": 213,
  },
  {
    "invoiceNumber": "INV-056",
    "invoiceDate": "2018-06-19",
    "jobCardNumber": "JC-018",
    "tax": 213,
    "part@9%": 140.04,
    "labour@18%": 140.04,
    "offer@12%": 140.04,
  }
]
```

the part@, labour@ and offer@ keys are dynamic. I want all the keys from the array object.
the result i want is

[
  'invoiceNumber',
  'invoiceDate',
  'jobCardNumber',
  'tax',
  'part@18%',
  'part@12%',
  'part@9%',
  'labour@18%',
  'offer@12%',
  'offer@9%'
]

Comment: Object.keys(myObj)

Comment: @jmargolisvt it will return [ '0', '1', '2', '3' ] i want ```['invoiceNumber','invoiceDate','jobCardNumber','tax','part@18%','part@12%','part@9%','labour@18%','offer@12%','offer@9%']```

Comment: `Object.keys()` will give you the keys of any object. Map the array with object.keys, flatten the result and then filter out the uniques. Just simple array operations. This should be trivial once you know `Object.keys()`. You only got [0,1,2,3] because you Object.key'ed the array instead of the objects inside the array.

Comment: Are you saying you want a distinct list of all the keys which occur, no matter which object they occur in, or how many times they occur?

Comment: @ADyson yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the objects with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and add their keys to the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
var data=[{invoiceNumber:"INV-056",invoiceDate:"2018-06-19",jobCardNumber:"JC-018",tax:43323},{invoiceNumber:"INV-056",invoiceDate:"2018-06-19",jobCardNumber:"JC-018",tax:213,"part@18%":140.04,"part@12%":140.04,"part@9%":140.04,"labour@18%":140.04,"offer@12%":140.04,"offer@9%":140.04},{invoiceNumber:"INV-056",invoiceDate:"2018-06-19",jobCardNumber:"JC-018",tax:213},{invoiceNumber:"INV-056",invoiceDate:"2018-06-19",jobCardNumber:"JC-018",tax:213,"part@9%":140.04,"labour@18%":140.04,"offer@12%":140.04}];

var result = [...data.reduce((all, el) => (Object.keys(el).forEach(k => all.add(k)),all), new Set)];

console.log(result);
```